# Why android studio apk rewrite my old App on installing to Android device?

Tags: java, android-studio

I have crate a copy of my old android project and made lots of update and change Android name as well from Android Manifest. But when ever I install this new App to android device , it just erase my old app and install my current app. How can I keep both old and New Apk on android app ?

Comment: Android considers APKs to be distinct if they have distinct applicationId. Have you updated that one as well?

Answer (score 1):

Open app level build.gradle file then under the android section there is an applicationId. You need to change it too.